# Test Type-Graphql with mongoose

Tags: node.js, graphql, ts-jest, typegraphql, typegoose

I am pretty new in unit testing, I want to test my application that is written in node, the technologies I use are express.js, type-graphql, and type-goose, I searched a lot on the web to find some articles to help me about how to do unit testing for a resolver that is written in type-graphql or how to do unit testing for a schema that is written in type-goose but unfortunately, I couldn't find any, now please help me solve the problem and at least pass me some useful links

this is the input:

```
import { Field, InputType } from 'type-graphql'

@InputType()
export class AdminLoginInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  email: string

  @Field(() => String)
  password: string
}
```

This is the Resolver:

```
import { Arg, Ctx, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from 'type-graphql'
import { AdminLoginInput } from '../../Inputs/Admins/admin.input'
import { Admin } from '../../schema/Admins/admin.schema'
import AdminService from '../../service/Admin/admin.service'
import { IContext } from '../../../interface/context'

@Resolver()
export default class AdminResolver {
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {
    this.adminService = new AdminService()
  }

  @Mutation(() => String)
  loginAdmin(@Arg('input') input: AdminLoginInput, @Ctx() context: IContext) {
    return this.adminService.loginAdmin(input, context)
  }

  @Query(() => Admin, { nullable: true })
  meAdmin(@Ctx() context: IContext) {
    return context.admin
  }
}
```

this is the schema

```
import { ObjectType, Field } from 'type-graphql'
import { getModelForClass, prop, pre, index } from '@typegoose/typegoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

@pre<Admin>('save', async function () {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) {
    return
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const hash = await bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt)

  this.password = hash
})
@ObjectType()
export class Admin {
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  _id: string

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop()
  firstname: string

  // @Field(() => String)
  // @prop()
  // name: string

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ unique: true })
  email: string

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop()
  gender: string

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop()
  language: string

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop({ default: Date.now() })
  created: string

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop()
  lastlogin: string

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop()
  updated: string

  @prop()
  password: string

  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  @prop()
  messages: [string]
}

export const AdminModel = getModelForClass<typeof Admin>(Admin)
```

This is the service:

```
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-server-express'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { AdminLoginInput } from '../../Inputs/Admins/admin.input'
import { AdminModel } from '../../schema/Admins/admin.schema'
import { IContext } from '../../../interface/context'
import { signJwt, verifyJwt } from '../../../../scripts/jwt'
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

class AdminService {
  async loginAdmin(input: AdminLoginInput, context: IContext) {
    try {
      const error = 'Invalid Email or Password'
      const admin: any = await AdminModel.findOne({ email: input.email }).lean()

      if (!admin) {
        throw new ApolloError(error)
      }

      const passwordIsValid = await bcrypt.compare(
        input.password,
        admin.password,
      )

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        throw new ApolloError(error)
      }

      const token = signJwt({ userId: admin._id.toString() })

      context.res.cookie('accessToken', token, {
        // domain: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
        // path: '/',
        sameSite: 'none',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        // process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ||
        // process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging',
        maxAge: 3.154e10,
      })

      return token
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

export default AdminService

a full image and its folder structure
[a complete image that contains files and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2112.png)

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add that too, I am using ApolloServer too

Comment: I am using ApolloServer in this application